# XPath SelectSingleNode with function usage

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm trying to use a function in a XPath expression:

```
substring-before(//span[@class='TextH3 LayoutSmallRow'], "PPAPI")
```

The C# code that processes the expression looks like this:

```
HtmlWeb Web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HtmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode PageNode = null;

HtmlDoc = Web.Load(tbUpdateCheckURL.Text);
PageNode = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(tbUpdatePattern.Text);
```

But this results in a exception (translated from german): "The expression must result in a node"

It sounds to me like the output from `substring-before` can't be "translated" to a `HtmlNode` type. Which is kind of logical of course. So my question is how to process a xpath expression that can use functions?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question directly, but ... have you tried CsQuery ? https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery I found HtmlAgilityPack much more difficult to use than this. Regarding your question, it would help if you provided a sample XML against which you are running this code.

Comment: So you're looking for a data type which can hold the result of an arbitrary xpath expression evaluation, is that right? (that is, you don't know whether you will get back a scalar, a node, or a nodeset)

Comment: unfortunately I cant add the inspected document. Since it is a webpage and not mine. @AakashM Yes thats kind of it. But I can't use `Object` since it throws an exception before returning anything.

Comment: In this case you would usually create a similar page that is yours, on which you are able to reproduce the issue. Part of research / troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HtmlDocument` of the HTML Agility Pack implements the `XPathNavigator` API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can simply call `CreateNavigator()` and then use the `Evaluate` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8(v=vs.110).aspx), for instance if you know you call `substring-before` in XPath and that way get a string you can use e.g.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml("<html><body><p>This is a <span>test: PPAPI.</span></p></body></html>");

        string result = (string)doc.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("substring-before(//span, 'PPAPI')");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

and the output is `test:`.